# .Net Core Azure AD Cloud how to get logged in user and access their Azure AD Security Groups to determine if they are in a group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

Azure AD Cloud how to get logged in user and access their Azure AD Security Groups to determine if they are in a group?  I have used WindowsIdentity to get this information in the past when we had AD on premises but it doesn't work for Azure AD cloud.  How could I get the logged on user information and all the security groups they are a member of?  I am lost on how to do this.  I have spent a lot of time trying to find answers but no luck.

Comment: Take a look at [Microsoft.Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a user is in an AD group via Azure AD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288567/how-to-check-if-a-user-is-in-an-ad-group-via-azure-ad) .. Please take a look.. it's very similar and should answer what you're looking for. I don't want to duplicate answer unless there is something different about your question, so feel free to comment.

Comment: Quick summary.. Two possible ways **1)** Use Microsoft Graph API to query groups with API's like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/checkMemberGroups` and similar `getMemberGroups` **2)** Enable group claims to come in as part of access token for your application by editing your application's manifest and setting `"groupMembershipClaims"` property to `"All"` or `"SecurityGroup"` as needed. Approach with Microsoft Graph API has an advantage.. since when user is part of too many groups, you don't get back groupids in token, but an overage indicator instead.

Comment: @RohitSaigal: Could you please add your comment in the answer.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT I've added an answer and elaborated a bit. Please feel free to suggest any additional info/edits that seem appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways you could do this:

1. **Use relevant Microsoft Graph APIs to query group information**

   Here are a couple of API's that seem relevant (you may find some others too)

   [Check member groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-checkmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0) -  This one will be helpful if you already know a set of groups that you want to check/validate membership against an already known list of groups and take some decisions.

   ```
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/checkMemberGroups
   ```

   In request body, you can provide `groupdIds`, i.e. a collection that contains the object IDs of the groups in which to check membership. Up to 20 groups may be specified.

   ```
    {
     "groupIds": [
          "fee2c45b-915a-4a64b130f4eb9e75525e",
          "4fe90ae065a-478b9400e0a0e1cbd540"
      ]
    }
   ```

   [user: getMemberGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0) - This one will be helpful if you want to get all the groups that this user belongs to. Returns all the groups that the user is a member of.

   Check for this one is Transitive, so you're assured that all groups will be returned. Upto 2046 returned as part of 1 request. It also works with O365 groups and you can filter down to SecurityEnabled groups using a parameter

   ```
   POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups
   ```
2. **Getting Group Membership Claims as part of Token**

   You can enable group claims to come in as part of the access token for your application by editing your application's manifest (this can be done directly in Azure Portal) and setting "groupMembershipClaims" property to "All" or "SecurityGroup" as needed.

   Once application manifest is updated as mentioned above, you can get Group Id's as part of claims. Here's a quick sample for a decoded JWT token

   [image]

**Comparing approaches and limit on the number of groups that can be returned as part of token**

Approach with Microsoft Graph API could have a couple of advantages, so choose appropriately based on your application's requirements/scenarios you want to support.

- You don't need to worry about overage scenario with Microsoft Graph API

  When you enable groupMembershipClaims to come in as part of token, if a user is part of too many groups, to ensure that the token size doesn't exceed HTTP header size limits, Azure AD limits the number of objectIds that it includes in the groups claim. If a user is member of more groups than the overage limit (150 for SAML tokens, 200 for JWT tokens), then Azure AD does not emit the groups claim in the token. Instead, it includes an overage claim in the token that indicates to the application to use the Graph API to retrieve the user's group membership.
- Access token will only include group Ids, if you need any other information like name of the group or any other property you need to query using Microsoft Graph API again.

**Consider using Application Roles**

Since you mention that you're about to use Group membership information to make some authorization decisions, please do know that Azure AD also provides a feature to define application specific roles that can then be assigned to users and help in making authorization decisions.

You can read more about it here on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles). These can be used alone or even in combination with group claims to take authorization decisions. These links might help as well.

- [Role-based and resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authorize)
- [Related SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856704/resource-based-authorization-with-azure-ad/54858044#54858044)

**Code Samples**

- [Add authorization using groups & group claims to an ASP.NET Core Web app that signs-in users with the Microsoft identity platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-2-Groups)
- [Add authorization using app roles & roles claims to an ASP.NET Core web app thats signs-in users with the Microsoft identity platform](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles)