# How should I handle in-app permissions with Azure AD SSO?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, adal

First project working with both single sign on and Azure, so maybe I'm just not doing it correctly.  Before using SSO, I would generate the token myself.  This allowed me to put whatever I wanted inside of the token, which I would use to determine permissions.  Using react-adal with Azure AD SSO, the token is generated client side and all I get is the user identity.  Following what I did in the past, I wrote a custom attribute to ensure the user has the appropriate permissions for the API call.  But rather than just pulling the information from the token that is passed with every request, I have to query the permissions every time they make a request, essentially doubling the database hits.

Is there a way for me to handle roles/permissions (admin, manager, user, read-only, etc) using single sign on and application driven permissions without querying the database every time I need to check permissions?

Previous process: 
`User visits site > enters credentials > server authenticates, gets permissions, generates token with permissions, returns it to client > client passes token on every request > server validates and parses token > attribute checks parsed token to ensure user has necessary permission > completes request`

Current process: `User visits site > client authenticates with Azure AD and gets token > client passes token on every request > server gets authentication information from token > server queries database to get users permissions > attribute checks query results to ensure user has necessary permission > completes request`

How can I make the current process better?  Every google result I've found has only covered authentication and hasn't gone deep enough into the actual application for me to find a "best practice" or even any practice.  Am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: The way that you are done I think that's correct as role model in your application might be different with AAD. If you worry about performance hitting database, putting redis cache in the middle

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the **Application Roles** related functionality with Azure AD to implement your custom RBAC. It should provide a good starting point for what you've mentioned, as roles collection will be available for you as part of incoming tokens from Azure AD.

### Application Roles

**Microsoft Documentation** - [Application Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/app-roles)

**Purpose** - These roles are defined in the Application Manifest for an application that your organization is developing and that is registered in your Azure Active Directory. These roles are very specific to your application and can be used in application's code to implement Authorization logic for the authenticated users.

**Sample Application** (that uses this concept and does what you're looking for) -

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD application roles & role claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-roleclaims)

**Quick Explanation**

1) Once you register your application with Azure AD, you can define custom roles (specific to your application) by editing the application manifest (JSON) in Azure AD.
Here's a sample JSON of what application role definition would look like:

```
"appRoles": 
[
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Creators can create Surveys",
    "displayName": "SurveyCreator",
    "id": "1b4f816e-5eaf-48b9-8613-7923830595ad",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyCreator"
  },
  {
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
      "User"
    ],
    "description": "Administrators can manage the Surveys in their tenant",
    "displayName": "SurveyAdmin",
    "id": "c20e145e-5459-4a6c-a074-b942bbd4cfe1",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "value": "SurveyAdmin"
  }
]
```

2) You will be able to assign these roles to Users/Groups/applications through Azure Portal or programmatically. (you could control the allowed member types for roles)

3) Now when the end users sign in to your application, the incoming Azure AD token will provide you a collection of role claims (based on whatever roles are assigned to the user) and you can take authorization decisions in your application.

```
if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")) { ... }
```

Here is another related documentation on Microsoft Docs - [Role-based and resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authorize)

I see you have also tagged asp.net-core in your question. So if you're working with ASP.NET core application, you could possibly make use of policies as shown in [Role-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authorize#create-policies) section of the link above.

```
public class SurveyCreatorRequirement : AuthorizationHandler<SurveyCreatorRequirement>, IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, SurveyCreatorRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Roles.SurveyAdmin) ||
            context.User.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, Roles.SurveyCreator))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, I've seen cases where people chose to do some authorization logic based on which groups the users belonged to. This is just information and not something you need to do. I'm sharing some details for both, Roles and Groups in this answer, but definitely look at Application Roles first. You could even use a combination of both Roles and Groups for your Authorization strategy.

### Groups

Groups can have multiple users or other groups as members. Again management of groups is possible through Azure Portal or programmatically.

**NOTE**: Groups are totally independent of your application, i.e. Azure AD groups can and do exist to serve a purpose of grouping members even without your application. Application Roles on the other hand are very specific to your application, they don't mean much to anyone except your application.

**Sample app which makes decisions based on Groups**

[Authorization in a web app using Azure AD groups & group claims](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims)

---

### Individual or Specific resource based authorization

Also know that when it gets to individual resource based authorization (and not a more generic role based authorization), then AFAIK you will need to go to your database or other persistent storage anyway because that's the only place which knows about a detailed mapping between permissions and individual objects in your system.

I have discussed about this in a related SO Post here - [Resource based Authorization with Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54856704/resource-based-authorization-with-azure-ad/54858044#54858044)